# Adding data to JSON file through UI

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a UI form wid 2 textboxes I need my Json file to be appended with the values present in 2 textboxes on clicking the submit button. Am using spring MVC architecture here. Just want to know how do I go about this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

OnClick of your button or any widget should append value like

```
JsonObject value = Json.createObjectBuilder()
     .add("firstName", "John")
     .add("lastName", "Smith")
     .add("age", 25)
     .add("address", Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("streetAddress", "21 2nd Street")
         .add("city", "New York")
         .add("state", "NY")
         .add("postalCode", "10021"))
     .add("phoneNumber", Json.createArrayBuilder()
         .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "home")
             .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
         .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "fax")
             .add("number", "646 555-4567")))
     .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the data in the request object in the controller from the form, take the values and append the values to JSON file through Java I/O.

Note: This is not suggestible. Generally, we make use of web applications only when we need to do CRUD operations with data from DB.